# Add data in an array of object with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need your help, I try to add(if it not exists) or update if exists datas in an array of Object in MongoDB.
Here is my Model

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false,
        trim: true
    },
    pseudo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    // password2: {
    //     type: String,
    //     required: true
    // },
    tags: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false,
        trim: true
    },
    coord: {
        type: Object,
        required: false,
        unique: false,
        trim: true
    },
    poll: [
        {
            tag: String,
            dates:  Array
        }
    ]
},
{
    timestamps: true,
});

const User = model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

My route

```
router.route('/calendar/:email').post((req, res) => { 
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then( (user) =>{
    console.log("user 1", user)
    User.bulkWrite([
      { 
        insertOne: { 
          "poll": { 
            "tag": req.body.selectedTag, 
            "dates": req.body.datesArray
          } 
        } 
      },
       { 
         updateOne: {
           "filter": {
             "tag" : req.body.selectedTag
           },
           "update": {
             $set: {
                 "dates": req.body.datesArray
             }
           },
        }
       }
    ])
  })
});
```

and the datas sended :

```
 email: 'john@gmail.com',
  selectedTag: 'work',
  dateArray: [ '2020-07-16T22:00:00.000Z' ]
```

I try many things like by findOneaAndUpdate, but I don't know how to add in the array "poll", objects with tag and the dates associated.

If somebody could help me it would be very nice !

Answer (score 0):

I shoul use add $addToSet or $push, depending if the element is unique or not.
Something like this:

```
"update": {
    "$addToSet": {
        "poll": { /*...*/ }  
    }
}
```

For reference:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: I've already try this, but I miss probably something. 
furthermore, I have this error ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot create property '$set' on number '0'```